# Using an AWS resource policy to conditionally allow traffic from Lambda's default-VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

For an Amazon EMR extract, transform, load (ETL) Step, I have a least-privilege bucket policy that [denies all actions to all resources unless the traffic is incoming through an S3 VPC Endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/block-s3-traffic-vpc-ip/) (shown below). Unfortunately, my Lambda function is denied access to the bucket because, [by default, Lambda runs functions in a secure VPC, which Lambda owns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html?icmpid=docs_lambda_console#vpc-internet) and is not connected to my account's default VPC. The documentation suggests that I connect my function to a VPC. However, due to some restrictions in my environment, I cannot connect my function to my VPC, and I have to use the Lambda default VPC only. What's the workaround for least privilege access to my S3 bucket from my VPC endpoint and Lambda function only?

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "Principal":"*",
         "Action":"s3:*",
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::inputs3bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::inputs3bucket/*"
         ],
         "Condition":{
            "StringNotEquals":{
               "aws:SourceVpce":"S3VPCGWEndpoint"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Lambda is interacting using an IAM role you could make use of the `NotPrincipal` policy by referencing the Lambdas IAM role.

The policy adjusted would look like the below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotPrincipal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/ExampleLambdaRoleFor123456789012"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::inputs3bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::inputs3bucket/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "aws:SourceVpce": "S3VPCGWEndpoint"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

By having this policy it will deny all actions where the IAM role is not the specified IAM role and the traffic did not come from the VPC endpoint.

Comment: With a bit of digging and troubleshooting, I realized that the Lambda function assumes the role you provide, and that assumed role must also be added to the S3 bucket policy. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/